Exicuting Quantum espresso vc-relax/relax calculation crashes with an error message saying more bands than PWs
I wanted to perform a vc-relax calculation for the  FeS2 lattice with 12 atoms. The error message reads as follows for every tasks from 1 to 12.
task #         9
     from memory_report : error #         1
     more bands than PWs!


(for other tasks just replace 9 with corresponding order.)
The code used to run was,
mpirun -np 12 home/physics/Desktop/qe-7.2/qe-7.2/PW/src/pw.x -inp Sn-FeS2.in > Sn-FeS2.out
The input file is as follows.
&CONTROL
   title           = "Sn-FeS2" 
   calculation     = 'vc-relax' 
   max_seconds     = 1.72800e+05 
   restart_mode    = 'from_scratch' 
   outdir          = '/home/physics/Desktop/a-an/' 
   wfcdir          = '/home/physics/Desktop/a-an/wfc/' 
   pseudo_dir      = '/home/physics/Desktop/a-an/pseudo/SSSP_1.3.0_PBE_precision/' 
   prefix          = 'Sn-FeS2' 
   disk_io         = 'medium' 
   verbosity       = 'high' 
   forc_conv_thr   = 1.00000e-03 
   nstep           = 100 
 /
 
 &SYSTEM
   ibrav           = 0
   celldm(1)       = 2.8
   nat             = 12
   ntyp            = 3
   ecutwfc         = 1.50000e+01 
   ecutrho         = 2.00000e+02 
   occupations     = "smearing" 
   degauss         = 1.00000e-02 
   smearing        = "gaussian" 
   nspin           = 2 
   starting_magnetization(1) = 0.00000e+00
   starting_magnetization(2) = 0.00000e+00
 /
 
 &ELECTRONS
   electron_maxstep = 200
   conv_thr        = 1.00000e-06 
   startingpot     = "atomic" 
   startingwfc     = "atomic+random" 
   mixing_beta     = 4.00000e-01 
   diagonalization = 'rmm-davidson' 
 /
 
 &IONS
   ion_dynamics    = 'damp' 
 /
 
 &CELL
   cell_dynamics   = 'none' 
 /
 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
   Fe   55.84500  Fe.pbe-spn-kjpaw_psl.0.2.1.UPF 
    S   32.00000  s_pbe_v1.4.uspp.F.UPF 
   Sn  118.71000  Sn_pbe_v1.uspp.F.UPF 

ATOMIC_POSITIONS angstrom 
   Fe      0.000000000    0.000000000    0.000000000    
   Sn      2.698412000    0.000000000    2.698412000    
   Fe      2.698412000    2.698412000    0.000000000    
   Fe      0.000000000    2.698412000    2.698412000    
    S      0.618583000    3.316995000    4.778241000    
    S      4.778241000    2.079829000    0.618583000    
    S      2.079829000    2.079829000    2.079829000    
    S      3.316995000    3.316995000    3.316995000    
    S      3.316995000    4.778241000    0.618583000    
    S      2.079829000    0.618583000    4.778241000    
    S      4.778241000    0.618583000    3.316995000    
    S      0.618583000    4.778241000    2.079829000   
     
K_POINTS automatic 
  6 6 6   1 1 1     

I'm not being able to solve it, please somebody help who know the problem.

that message means you have more filled bands than you have states in your hamiltonian, which is not sensible. ecutwfc sets the size of your hilbert space. indeed 15 Ry is very low and is very likely not converging total energy. try increasing ecutwfc and see if the error disappears, but note that you need to converge physical properties wrt. ecutwfc (and possibly ecutrho, but 200 Ry is already very large).

15 Ry is too low. You are using the pseudopotentials from SSSP efficiency set. From their cutoff table, the minimum suggested ectwfc should be set as 90 Ry and ecutrho should be set as 1080 Ry. However, you should choose a little bit larger or do a convergence test since the minimum values do not usually give a good result.

Thanks to all who helped by answering this problem; it has been solved now.
